# Do I have to create a nested symbol to use motion tween inside a symbol?

Tags: adobe-animate

I've created a graphic symbol that includes a single shape and nothing else. Now I want to apply a motion tween to that shape inside the symbol timeline: I want it to wiggle back'n'forth so I can reuse that wiggling symbol many times on the main timeline.

However, the program keeps demanding that I make another symbol out of that shape before I apply a motion tween.

This just seems weird: having a symbol that includes nothing but a single shape, and then creating another symbol that includes nothing but that same shape just so I can nest it inside that first symbol and apply a motion tween to it. Just wanted to make sure that I'm doing everything right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have a loop animation nested with in a symbol that you can tween on the main stage, you would:

A. Make a graphic symbol, then edit its timeline to animate a movie clip with shape tweens. Then on the main stage, you could motion tween the graphic symbol.

B. Make a movie clip symbol, then edit its timeline to animate a movie clip with motion tweens. Then on the main stage, you could motion tween the movie clip symbol.

Source: https://www.proprofs.com/discuss/q/430283/you-want-have-loop-animation-nested-with-symbol-that-can-twe

And also look this [3d modeling services](https://3danimationrendering.com/3d-modeling/) hope it will be help you